# I need to change the font type and weight in this jquery code

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have no idea how jquery works, but I have this wordpress plugin that works great and does exactly what I want. Thing is, I'd like to customize the "Stream Live!" prompt a bit.

Here's the code:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function ($) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + marctvtwitchsettings.channelname,
            headers: {
                'Client-ID': 'c63pi9xlfs7bqtt0h9otarutq6nc1h1'
            },
            success: function (a) {
                if (a.stream) {
                    var submenu = '';

                    if (marctvtwitchsettings.showmeta == 'on') {
                        var submenu = '<ul class="sub-menu"><li class="menu-item twitch-meta">' +
                            '<a class="twitch-link" target="_blank" title="' + a.stream.viewers + ' viewers" href="' + marctvtwitchsettings.channelurl + '">' +
                            '<p>' + a.stream.game + '</p>' +
                            '<img src="' + a.stream.preview.medium + '"></li></ul>' +
                            '</a>';
                    }

                    $(marctvtwitchsettings.menuselector).append('<li id="twitch-status" class="twitch-status menu-item">' +
                        '<a class="twitch-link" target="_blank" title="' + a.stream.viewers + ' viewers" href="' + marctvtwitchsettings.channelurl + '">Stream Live!</a>' +
                        submenu +
                        '</li>');
                    $('.offline', marctvtwitchsettings.menuselector).hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How do I make the "Stream Live!" bold? How do I change the font family?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function ($) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + marctvtwitchsettings.channelname,
        headers: {
            'Client-ID': 'c63pi9xlfs7bqtt0h9otarutq6nc1h1'
        },
        success: function (a) {
            if (a.stream) {
                var submenu = '';

                if (marctvtwitchsettings.showmeta == 'on') {
                    var submenu = '<ul class="sub-menu"><li class="menu-item twitch-meta">' +
                        '<a class="twitch-link" target="_blank" title="' + a.stream.viewers + ' viewers" href="' + marctvtwitchsettings.channelurl + '">' +
                        '<p>' + a.stream.game + '</p>' +
                        '<img src="' + a.stream.preview.medium + '"></li></ul>' +
                        '</a>';
                }

                $(marctvtwitchsettings.menuselector).append('<li id="twitch-status" class="twitch-status menu-item">' +
                    '<a class="twitch-link" style="font-weight: bold; font-family: Consolas,"courier new";" target="_blank" title="' + a.stream.viewers + ' viewers" href="' + marctvtwitchsettings.channelurl + '">Stream Live!</a>' +
                    submenu +
                    '</li>');
                $('.offline', marctvtwitchsettings.menuselector).hide();
            }
        }
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @Woland: This would at least deserve an accept (click the checkmark). I upvoted since the solution is good.

Answer (score 0):

It has the class `.twitch-link`, so you just need to style that class. The right way to do it would be to add these rules to your CSS, but you could also do it inline with the `style=`attribute.

```
.twitch-link {
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or inline version:

```
<a class="twitch-link" style="font-family: 'Arial'; font-weight: bold;" target="_blank" title="' + a.stream.viewers + ' viewers" href="' + marctvtwitchsettings.channelurl + '">Stream Live!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick to select **ONLY** this particular link and make it bold.

```
$('a:contains("Stream Live!")').css({"font-weight":"bold"});
```

For the explanations... It could be a little long.
But you can read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_contains.asp) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/) for a start.

You can place many other CSS rules in the `.css()` method, like this:

```
.css({"font-weight":"bold","font-size":"2em","text-decoration":"none","color":"red"});
```